# many ImageViews positioning on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-gridlayout

I have a dynamic list of `ImageView`s. Now I want them to show on my screen, but in a `ScrollView`er.

The layout could be

```
-------------------------
| Image 1 |   Image 2   |
-------------------------
|       Image 3         |
-------------------------
| Image 4     | Image 5 |
-------------------------
```

or

```
-------------------------
|    Image 1  | Image 2 |
-------------------------
| Image 3 |   Image 4   |
-------------------------
|        Image 5        |
-------------------------
```

The numbers of `ImageView`s at one row, depends on the image and screen size. Has someone an idea, how I could achieve this?

PS: The height of the `ImageView`s should be equal.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at this project on GitHub https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo and patch it to your needs

Comment: This could be a solution. Thanks. I'll test it. Edit: Hmm, I have to define how many columns it should have.

Comment: use std ListView with an Adapter whose each item is a horizontal LinearLayout where you will add your ImageViews, the number of them will be computed based on their Bitmap dimensions

Comment: Perhaps you can also take a look at this [AndroidStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) library from etsy.

Comment: The StaggeredGridView (etsy or maurycyw) do need a fix column number, but I need a dynamic number of columns. And etsy needs minSDK 10, but my app needs minSdk 9.

Comment: @pslink Can you post an example? I have now one `ListView` and my `Adapter` is an `ArrayAdapter`. In the `getView` function I load an `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView`. What do I see? One normal List of images, one per row. :(